# Show and hide for two different <div> elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am working on hide and show functionality.
When I click the wireless it should open the corresponding div element.
When I click one li it opens the corresponding div.
I am getting the error:

> cannot read property display.

How can I fix it provided with my code below:

http://jsbin.com/zutediki/1/edit

```
function toggle(){
    content.style.display = content.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

Comment: hey he has provided the jsbin link..

Comment: The functionality you're looking for can be found on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/2syzQ/).  This was a demo for a different SO question, but the functionality needed is the same.

Comment: @Pawal, still question remains What is content?

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same `id`... that's not valid.

Comment: Oh, god... you've also got free-floating `<li>` elements in there. Permitted parents of `<li>` are `<ul>`, `<ol>`, and `<menu>` ([reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-context))

Answer (score 2):

Use [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) like so ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/rsv4b/)):

```
$(".service-list__item").click(function(){
   $(this).next(".content").toggle(); 
});
```

<sub>See also [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)</sub>

Issues:

1. You have multiple elements with the same `id`.
2. You've also got free-floating list items

   - Permitted parents of `li` are `ul`, `ol`, and `<menu>` ([reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-context))

Comment: @user3479564 Yes, but that belongs in a new question.